# In orienteering/navigation, what is a handrail feature?

Tags: navigation, terminology, orienteering

One of the terms in orienteering/navigation is "handrail feature".

What exactly does this term mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A handrail feature is something that you can **travel paralleled to in order to reach your destination.**

A good example of this would be a stream/river as while you wouldn't want to follow directly beside it due to any swamps/marshes/beaver dams or trying to follow the bends, staying parallel to it, would help **prevent you from getting lost.**

[image]

A few other examples would be long ridges, trails, roads, and valleys.