# What is a catch feature in orienteering?

Tags: navigation, terminology, orienteering

On of the terms used in orienteering is "catch feature".

What exactly is a catch feature and how would a catch feature help one with navigating in the outdoors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A catch feature is a feature that you will run into, if you have gone too far.

[image: Travel parallel to handrail to run into catch]

As you can see above, if you are using the stream as a [handrail feature](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/in-orienteering-navigation-what-is-a-handrail-feature) to get to the bridge in order to cross, the trail acts as a catch feature.

If you are heading towards a catch feature and not following a handrail, then you will want to [aim off](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14916/why-would-one-aim-off-when-navigating-with-a-map-and-compass#answer-14917).

Some examples of things that can act as handrail features include streams, trails, roads, and ridge lines.

Comment: You could probably have provided both information about handrail and catch-features in one bigger question about orienteering, but take my four upvotes, you clever racoon :D (but for real, if you have more of these information, and can summarize them in one big post, it could become a to-go for every orienteering-realted question. I'd read that!

Comment: @Peter1807 Thanks, I will probably write more of these